# access to virtualhost from another pc xampp

Tags: xampp, virtualhost

may I ask question about the Apache Virtual Host config?

I use XAMPP, and my ipv4 is 192.168.1.7

I have configured my host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc...) like

```
127.0.0.1       g4.org
192.168.1.7       g4.org
```

and C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf like

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.7:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/rs"
    ServerName g4.org
    ServerAlias www.g4.org
</VirtualHost>
```

The virtualhost works perfectly on the machine that has installed xampp .
but the problem is in the another machine(PC) [SAME LAN] if i go to http://192.168.1.7 the page load and work perfectly

### but

if i go to this link http://g4.org the page won't load and say

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Answer (score 0):

In the another machine, just put the "192.168.1.7  g4.org" at the host file.

Comment: are there another way without that i need it directly

Comment: Hmmm..MAYBE, you can try to do a redirection on your router or switch, that, when someone type g4.org, the router will send to your ip. But i don't really know how to do that, sorry. :/

Comment: **ok** anyone now how to do it

Comment: @MGCC: You could try to add a DNS entry for `g4.org` to your local DNS server.

Comment: how add that and where are dns server